# How to pull partition value from HDFS path using sed/grep/awk when partition value is dynamic

Tags: sed, grep, hdfs, partition

I am trying to save partition value from hdfs path to a file for different tables

Tried using sed to pull last 8 digits but since partition value changes (sometimes it may be YYYYMMDD sometimes YYYYMM) trying to see if we can grep data_dt from hdfs path instead of using sed.

### Code used

```
hadoop fs -ls <hdfs_path> | sort -k6,7 | tail -2 > partition_info.txt

partitions=$(sed -e 's,.*\(.\{8\}\)$,\1,'  partition_info.txt)

echo $partitions > partition_tables.txt
```

### Desired Output example

```
20200531

202005

202004

20200601
```

Hadoop fs -ls output looks like this

```
drwxr-xr-x - kmedgel kmedgego 0 2020-05-30 09:33 /km/gold/edge_gold/otsd_cmpl/data_dt=20200530 
drwxr-xr-x - kmedgel kmedgego 0 2020-05-31 09:33 /km/gold/edge_gold/otsd_cmpl/data_dt=20200531 
drwxr-xr-x - kmedgel kmedgego 0 2020-06-01 09:34 /km/gold/edge_gold/otsd_cmpl/data_dt=20200601 
drwxr-xr-x - kmedgel kmedgego 0 2020-06-02 09:34 /km/gold/edge_gold/otsd_cmpl/data_dt=20200602 
drwxr-xr-x - kmedgel kmedgego 0 2020-06-03 09:55 /km/gold/edge_gold/otsd_cmpl/data_dt=20200603
```

Comment: What command do you run to get the partition info which you want to process? Sample source output will help.

Comment: As @Technext said, give us what `hadoop fs -ls <hdfs_path>` looks like without the pipe to `sort` or `tail`.  You can give an abbreviated snippit

Comment: drwxr-xr-x   - kmedgel kmedgego          0 2020-05-30 09:33 /km/gold/edge_gold/otsd_cmpl/data_dt=20200530
drwxr-xr-x   - kmedgel kmedgego          0 2020-05-31 09:33 /km/gold/edge_gold/otsd_cmpl/data_dt=20200531
drwxr-xr-x   - kmedgel kmedgego          0 2020-06-01 09:34 /km/gold/edge_gold/otsd_cmpl/data_dt=20200601
drwxr-xr-x   - kmedgel kmedgego          0 2020-06-02 09:34 /km/gold/edge_gold/otsd_cmpl/data_dt=20200602
drwxr-xr-x   - kmedgel kmedgego          0 2020-06-03 09:55 /km/gold/edge_gold/otsd_cmpl/data_dt=20200603

Comment: Kindly put it in the post itself

Comment: Used this and it worked while IFS="=" read -r notNeed data_dt

Comment: Following will print everything after `date_dt=` if that's what you want: `sed 's/.*data_dt=\(.*\)/\1/' file-name`

Comment: @Neena: If what you tried worked for you, it's good to post that solution as an answer so others could benefit.

Answer (score 0):

Used while loop saying notNeed for the whole statement except for the field we are looking for i.e data_dt

**Answer**

while IFS="=" read -r notNeed data_dt

do

{

echo $data_dt

}

done